# PHP - if int reached to n

Tags: php

Take these levels:

```
level1 = 0days
level2 = 30days
level3 = 90days
```

All these levels are totally dynamic. Admin can alter number of levels and duration of levels at any time.

I am recording `numberOfDailyLogin` in a series, so if user not login even for 1 day meter reset to 0.

I am trying to give user a special level tag on basis of `numberOfDailyLogin`

I have a solution already by running a `while loop` from `0` to `numberOfDailyLogin` and update `variable` once `>=` `daysRequired` for login.

**But I don't want it this way, want something easy**

I am totally clueless at this point, I can't hardcode any of the
value, so please if you are interest please give some suggestion.

**#Edit1**

```
// json response for levels
{
    "status": 200,
    "body": [
        {
            "name": "level1",
            "after_days": 0,
        },
        {
            "name": "level2",
            "after_days": 50,
        },
        {
            "name": "level3",
            "after_days": 180,
        }
    ]
}

function getLevel($allLevels, $numberOfDailyLogins) {
    foreach ($allLevels as $l) {
        if ($numberOfDailyLogins > $l['after_days']) {
            return $l['name'];
        }
    }
}
```

**Problem is if `numberOfDailyLogins=51`.. so it should show level2... cause after 50 days userLevel reached to level2.. but my code return level1 which is totally wrong.**

Comment: `want something easy`...why, what exactly is "difficult" about your existing solution? And what sort of thing would you define as "easy"? That's very subjective. It's not really clear what the problem is, and we can't guess, especially without seeing the full code of it.

Comment: @ADyson thanks for asking something this time... days are dynamic so admin can set i to like 7, 21, 81... totally  upto admin choice

Comment: Ok. But you can put them into variables (maybe using an array) and use them in your algorithm. Not really sure why that would be stopping you? Again we can't see your current solution so we can't really see what's puzzling you.

Comment: @ADyson check the #Edit1

Comment: Undefined variable `$dateDiff`

Comment: @jibsteroos Fixed!  codes are pretty big just pasted a little bit here..

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? The given code with a foreach loop does not look like something that impacts the performance in any way, even if you were using like a dozen levels

Comment: @NicoHaase  I already mentioned codes are pretty big i am doing some other calculations too at same night that's why its time consuming process.. but problem is my codes not working and I want a suggesiton

Comment: Don't `return $l['name'];` immediately. On the first iteration 51 is greater than 0, `return` breaks the loop and doesn't even check your 50 limit. Set a variable to `$l['name'];` and break the loop when less than

Comment: @CodingWithRoyal, I think there are two problems that you wish to address. One is getting the loop to work correctly, and the other is to make it better or more performant, right?

Comment: @ChrisHaas yes bro

Comment: We try to focus on one and only one thing when trying to help people. I would suggest changing your question to what you are trying to do, show the `getLevel` function, explain the result that you are getting and the result that you want. Very straight-forward questions like that usually get answers pretty quickly.

Comment: If your code is not working, please share more details. You haven't even shared PHP code that compiles and does anything, so it's pretty difficult to see **why** your code might not work as expected

Answer (score 2):

@brombeer suggestion works for me, Thanks mate

```
function getLevel($allLevels, $numberOfDailyLogins) {
    $level = null;
    foreach ($allLevels as $l) {
        if ($numberOfDailyLogins> $l['after_days']) {
            $level = $l;
        }
    }
    // TO-DO... do whatever you want
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. Might want to add a `} else { break; }` so you exit the loop when it's less than and don't check the rest

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple logic error - your code returns after the first iteration because the value is already greater than 0 (the first level in the list).

One simple solution is to search the array in reverse instead:

```
function getLevel($allLevels, $numberOfDailyLogins) {
    for ($i = count($allLevels) -1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
        if ($numberOfDailyLogins > $allLevels[$i]['after_days']) {
            return $allLevels[$i]['name'];
        }
    }
}
```

Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3b00c6d182676411915cae1fbb21a1afba2548e8